# Exposed Filters View is not functional with Anonymous Users

Tags: views

I created a Filtering Search with Multiple Exposed Filters. It all has been working fine except one thing; when I logout as an admin and use the site as an anonymous user, exposed filters don't work.

The screenshot of my exposed filters form is below:-

[image]

In a functional scenario, When I click on any value, let's say EMEA, the form auto-sumbits and show hierarchical values in all the below filters and show the data on the right side.

As an example, When I click `EMEA`, the form auto-submits, and all the `offices` from `EMEA` appear in the lower filter of `Filter by Office` and results are shown.

The problem is that all the filters, data and values are shown for anonymous users but not auto-submitting takes place. It seems it just refreshes the page when I click on any filter.

Any idea?

Best.

### P.S

I used two modules within it:-

1. Better Exposed Filters (for making filters more readable)
2. Views Hacks (to use Views Selective Exposed Filters for showing hierarchy within Filters)

Comment: Drupal does not provide auto-submit in core, neither does Views module. So please tell us how you implemented it if we are to help you what's wrong with this functionality.

Comment: Should I paste the View here? Even when I remove the auto-submit functionality, it still doesn't work ... There is something that is not letting it submit the form variables. With Admin login, I can see the URL filled with Query Variables on submit, but with anonymous mode, the page just refreshes on submit button press and there's no change/submitting of query in the URL :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I had LDAP module enabled and that was de-authorizing the access. Had to deactivate it.

Thanks a lot guys.